# Database setup using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to setup a local database on my laptop using python. I saw the tutorial on the internet and need to know few things before I get onto this:-

```
import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

    c = conn.cursor()

    # Create table
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
                 (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')

    # Insert a row of data
    c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
```

In the above code, The data is inserted manually. But I have .csv file in my local drive and the data in that file is separated by space.

how do i insert the data in that file into the database? Also, I would like to extract data after that in excel format. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Mahi

Comment: i saw the above code and wondering if i can insert the data from a file available on my desktop.

Comment: Also I have used SAS programming to do this task and successfully completed it and now wanna try python

Comment: A .csv file that is separated by a space???

Comment: I would suggest splitting your question into two: (1) How do I insert a .csv file into a database (2) how do I extract data from a database into excel...

Comment: the extension of the file is .csv and I can open that file using excel. I guess there is no "," but only space is given between each data. "John" "21"...etc

Comment: Could you not just read from Excel directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `csv` module to read data from a CSV file. It has "dialect" settings that allow you to specify the column separator and quoting style. I recommend using the `csv.DictReader` class to read in your data, since it allows you to refer to the read-in data by name.

Answer (score 0):

A fast google search pointed me to [python-excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) to read excel files with Python.
And Python has a [csv Module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) included.

So simply extract the needed data, iterate over it and insert it into your database, seems like you already got the needed queries

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", date, text, stext, qty, price)
```

You can also pass an iterable of tuples to `c.execute` which will execute the query multiple times and you don't have to iterate over your data.